# mongoose populate field using _id of its own document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, chat

I'm creating an appliction using MEAN stack in which i've one to one chat feature. I'm using mongoose and have 3 schemas :

**Users**

```
{
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    profile_pic: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    }
}
```

**Messages**

```
{
    message : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    timestamp : {
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    from : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    conversation_id : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required : true
    }
}
```

**Conversations**

```
{
    users : [ { 
                type: type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                ref : User 
             }]
}
```

Now, when user goes to his messenger i want to show him all his past conversations with latest messages so right now i'm exceuting find command on Conversation and populating User

then after getting all conversations i'm executing find command for each conversation to get their latest message, so by this there are so many find operations are done on database in single request. i.e. why i need some solution like populate latest message for each conversation ( like i can populate using _id of conversation )

**Edit**

Here is the code i'm using right now :

```
let completeConversations = [];
conversation.find({ "users": req.body.token_data.id }).populate({ path: 'users', select: 'name profile_pic' }).exec((err, conversations) => {
    if (err) throw err
    if (conversations.length == 0) {
        res.status(200);
        res.json({  message: "No Conversations Found" })
    } else {
        conversations.forEach(element => {
            messages.find({ conversation_id: element._id }).sort('-timestamp').limit(1).exec((err, message) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(200);
                    res.json({ message: "Latest Message Not Found", conversations })
                } else {
                    element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
                    element.latest = message[0];
                    completeConversations.push(element);
                }
                if (completeConversations.length === conversations.length) {
                    res.json(completeConversations)
                }
            })
        });
    }
})
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: right now i'm executing find command for each conversation to get latest message, but i want it to be get populate, is there any way to use populate to get result like this?